# android - Как получить chmod файла?

Tags: android, chmod

Нужно делать проверку на `chmod 777`, но даже понятия не имею как?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `ls -l`.

Comment: я понял) нашел) но как именно запросить команду в рантайме и получить ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения характеристик доступа, Вам нужно что-то подобное:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-l").directory(new File(file.getParent()));
Process process = processBuilder.start();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
out.flush();
String resultLine;
resultLine = in.readLine();

while (resultLine != null) {
    System.out.println(resultLine);
}
```

Первые 10 символов полученной строки – это `permissions`.

Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837572).

**PS. root required**.

Comment: Ура!! Спасибо))